# Connection is closed exception even if it is open

Tags: c#, dapper

I have the following method in my repository:

```
public async void UpdateName(int id, string name)
{
    var connection = dataContext.GetDatabase().Connection;
    var initialState = connection.State;

    try
    {
        if (initialState == ConnectionState.Closed)
            await connection.OpenAsync();

        await connection.ExecuteAsync("myproc", new { id, name}, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (initialState == ConnectionState.Closed)
            await connection.CloseAsync();
    }
}
```

An exception `Connection is closed` is thrown when calling `ExecuteAsync`. When debugging the code and checking the connection state right before the call, the state is `Open`.

Additionally, I was looking at the `ExecuteAsync` implementation and I see that the method tries to open the connection too.

So my questions are:

1. Why is the exception thrown?
2. Can I remove the open/close connection in my method?

**UPDATE**

This is the stack trace:

> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQuery(IAsyncResult >asyncResult)
> at >System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult >iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean >requiresSynchronization)
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Dapper.SqlMapper.d__39.MoveNext()
> at MyApp.MyRepository.d__5.MoveNext() in >C:\myapp\myrepository.cs:line 91
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.b__128_1(Object >state)
> at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.Execute()
> at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
> at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()

Comment: *"Why is the exception thrown?"* probably because *"the method tries to open the connection too."* :) *"Can I remove the open/close connection in my method?"* try it and tell us

Comment: Still throws the exception after removing my open/close code.

Comment: Dapper's ExecuteAsync only opens the connection if it isn't open already - basically it does exactly what your try/finally already does ([here](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper/blob/main/Dapper/SqlMapper.Async.cs#L641-L652)); my guess here is that `connection` is being shared between concurrent uses (perhaps multiple parallel requests, in a web-server) - and multiple unrelated executions are trying to open/close it separately leading to chaos; is this a possibility?

Comment: @MarcGravell The connection (ie. datacontext) is a property of my UoW class. I have a method that calls the above method in a loop. This loop is within an Autofac child scope that changes the UoW instance from `PerDependency` to `SingleInstance`. So the connection should always remain open. So I can't see how multiple threads might be using the same connection.

Comment: @IvanDebono that's still the most likely cause I can think of here

Comment: @MarcGravell I added the stack trace to the question. Could it be that multiple threads are using the same connection at the same time?

Comment: The pattern for database connections is Create=>Use=>;Dispose. Never try to keep your connection, connection pooling is your friend.

Comment: @IvanDebono what is the lifetime of `dataContext` ? if that ends up being shared, then: the connection is shared, and you're toast; of course, you could also be sharing the connection *without* sharing the `dataContext`, but fundamentally: *you cannot use a connection concurrently from two independent and overlapping paths*